# how to generate a random convex piecewise-linear function

Tags: python, numpy, random, piecewise

I want to generate a toy example to illustrate a convex piecewise linear function in `python`, but I couldn't figure out the best way to do this. What I want to do is to indicate the number of lines and generate the function randomly.

A convex piecewise-linear function is defined as:

[image: 1]

For instance, if I want to have four linear lines, then I want to generate something as shown below.

[image]

Since there are four lines. I need to generate four increasing random integers to determine the intervals in x-axis.

```
import random 
import numpy as np
random.seed(1)

x_points = np.array(random.sample(range(1, 20), 4))
x_points.sort()
x_points = np.append(0, x_points)

x_points
[0 3 4 5 9]
```

I can now use the first two points and create a random linear function, but I don't know how I should continue from there to preserve the convexity. Note that a function is called convex if the line segment between any two points on the graph of the function does not lie below the graph between the two points.

Comment: The slope needs to increase for each segment.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I believe there should be some other rules too to make sure that pieces are connected.

Comment: That the pieces are connected *is* the rule. If you have the x intervals and the slopes, this defines all segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slope increases monotonically by a random value from the range [0,1), starting from 0. The first y value is also zero, see the comments.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

x_points = np.random.randint(low=1, high=20, size=4)
x_points.sort()
x_points = np.append(0, x_points)  # the first 0 point is 0

slopes = np.add.accumulate(np.random.random(size=3))
slopes = np.append(0,slopes)  # the first slope is 0

y_incr = np.ediff1d(x_points)*slopes
y_points = np.add.accumulate(y_incr)
y_points = np.append(0,y_points)  # the first y values is 0
```

A possible output looks like this:

```py
print(x_points)
print(y_points)
# [ 0  1  4 13 16]
# [ 0.          0.          2.57383685 17.92061306 24.90689622]
```

[image]

To print this figure:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_points,y_points, '-o', label="convex piecewise-linear function")
ax.legend()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. If I generate a random x point and would like to get the corresponding y value, how can I achieve it in your example? Also, could you kindly share the code that you used to plot the graph? Thanks

Comment: See the last paragraph for the update on the graph. The code doesn't generate the points 1 by 1, but in a vectorized way for the whole range. If you need more points, it is the easiest to rerun the whole program with different settings requesting for more points.

Comment: I'm analyzing the code and realized that based on your code, the first linear function is always zero function. I guess you should generate four points for slope rather than appending zero.

Comment: You are right, it is 0, intentionally, just as the first `x_point` and the first `y_point`. Should you prefer non-0 first slope, generate 4 random values instead of 3 and remove the append 0 part.

Comment: Could you add the plotting code in your post in a proper way, please? I'm receiving an error when I try it on my side.

Comment: It was not python. [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is a great plotting program, works well with latex. I replaced the figure with the output from matplotlib, using python.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It was a great help to me!

Answer (score 0):

make sure the gradient (=dx/dy) is increasing.
Pseudocode:

```
s = 1;
x = 0;
y = 0;
n = 4;
while(--n>0)
{
  //increase x randomly
  dx = rand(3);
  dy = dx * s;
  x += dx;
  y += dy; 
  //increase gradient randomly
  s += rand(3);
  print x + "/" +y;
}
```